# How do I make AptonCD restore packages present on ISO on local disk

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I used APtonCD to create a ISO image of packages I have installed on my install. I'm trying to restore the image, but it seems to look for the restore image present in my default drive.

How do I get AptonCD to look at the packages present in the ISO on the local disk?

Comment: what do you mean by `. You can create an image but can never restore...`

Comment: As hal is not present, it will not show file open dialog. Installing hal solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly after installing Linux mint 10, update system using the update manager.

After
copy contents on the APTonCD from the packages folder except (aptoncd-metapackage_date.deb) to 
**/var/cache/apt/archives** (remember to open this with sudo nautilus in terminal)

Now open **Synaptic package manager** select packages to install.
remember to connect to the Internet so that packages that you don't have
will be downloaded before install.

This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install hal. Otherwise, it will keep asking for the image on your CD drive.

`sudo apt-get install hal`

After executing this command, try AptOnCD again. You will be able to select the ISO file.